# Excel search for value add value next from colum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I need a bit of help I have a huge excel sheet with materials

```
Material   Quantity 
AA          10
BB          11
CC          52
DD          60
AA          16
DD          10
FF          20
QQ          400
RR          25
TT          80
AA          10
AA          122
FF          11
FF          12
GG          1
TT          15
```

What I would like to be able to do is to select the Value from 1st colum, let's say look for AA and automatically to get the SUM off all the Quantity AA ( In this example 10+16+10+122 = 158)

Comment: `SUMIF(A:A,"AA",B:B)`

Comment: or use a pivot for all values

Comment: Watch the video at [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B).

Answer (score 0):

Although a [SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) formula does work and might be placed wherever convenient (I have shown  @Scott Craner's in D15) a PivotTable (as suggested by @Zahiro Mor) might be a lot more useful, not only because it can sum all Materials at one time but also for further analysis:

[image]